# How can I create a move attr constructor inside a class?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a move attribute constructor in my class.

My class is a Date class.It has this attributes: day, month and year. Like this:

```
private:
     int day;
     int month;
     int year;
```

I'm trying to call like this:

```
 Date& Date::operator =(Date&& data) {
   day = data.day;
   month = data.month;
   year = data.year;

   data.day = 0; data.month = 0; data.year = 0;
   return *this;
}
```

In my Date.h

```
 Date& Date::operator =(Date&& data);
```

Errors: - Extra qualification 'Date::' on member 'operator=' in Date.h
- Expected ',' or '...' before '&&' token
Whats is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I copied wrong. Edited.

Comment: Why do you think something's wrong?

Comment: "Whats wrong?" Did you try to use it as you posted it? Do you get any error messages? Do you get results different from what you would expect? You should first just try and see what happens.

Comment: There isn't any point in zeroing the elements of `data`. Other than that, the default move constructor would be fine (noting that moving ints is no different to copying them.)

Comment: Ok. I will edit, I will specify better.

Comment: If you are editing anyhow you could also change "mouth" to "month" ;)

Comment: I like to use RHS and/or LHS as parameter names when overloading operators, I think it makes for easier to read code. Calling the parameter data when the class name is Date is just asking for trouble, especially given the high number of programmers that dyslexic (myself included)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's this line in the header:

```
 Date& Date::operator =(Date&& data);
```

That should be declared inside the class definition, in which case the Date:: is at best unnecessary and at worst liable to cause interesting errors.

If it's declared outside the class definition, it's just wrong.